# How to calculate percentages in a group using SQL

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a table employee

`(ID, status, department)`

Suppose the status can only be 'f' or 'c'.

How to calculate the % of f's and c's in each department?

Update 1:  the four fields in the output should be

`A.  DEPTNAME   B.  F_PCT     C.  C_PCT    D. EMPCOUNT in that Dept`

Update 2:  some departments might have all F's or all C's.  In either case, they should be reported with either Col B or Col C being 0 and the other being 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function to accomplish that:

```
select department, status,
(count(status) / sum(count(status)) over (partition by department)) * 100.0 as percentage
from employee
group by department, status
```

Comment: Could you update your question please with the desired output?

Comment: Building on this, to report %f and %c for each dept and headcount: 

```with stats as ( select dept, "EmpStatus" as status,
(count("EmpStatus") / sum(count("EmpStatus")) over (partition by dept)) * 100.0::float as pct , count("EmpStatus") as TotalEmpCount
from employee group by "Department" , "EmpStatus"  
) 

select dept,   
case when min(status) = 'Contractor' then (100 - min(pct)) else min(pct)  end  as FTE_PCT ,
case when min(status) = 'FTE' then (100 - min(pct)) else min(pct)  end as C_PCT ,  sum(totalempcount) as emp_count  
from stats 
group by dept```

Comment: The desired output are these 4 fields:

``` DEPT         F_PCT      C_PCT     EMP_COUNT ```

Comment: For example, 

``` HR      0      100    1```